# org-mode TODO items not recognized first time

Tags: org-mode, todo

My org-mode TODO keywords are set as follows:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "NITPICKING(!)" "NITS_SENT(!)" "NITS_DONE(!)" "PROOFS_SENT(!)"
          "PROOFS_RECEIVED(!)" "ACS_RECEIVED(!)" "ACS_ASSIGNED(!)"
          "ACS_DONE(!)" "|" "READY(!)")))
```

I have a headline that starts in the `NITPICKING` state. Here is what happens:

- I press `C-c C-t` to call `org-todo`. State changes from `NITPICKING` to `NITS_SENT`, as it should, but syntax highlighting gets lost for that headline.
- I press `C-c C-t` again, it puts me back in the `NITPICKING` state, with correct highlighting.
- I press `C-c C-t` again, it puts me in the `NITS_SENT` state, now with correct highlighting.
- Further calls to `org-todo` work correctly.

So it's just the first transition that's getting screwed up. Here is what the timestamps look like:

```
  - State "NITS_SENT"  from "NITPICKING" [2016-05-23 Mon 13:27]
  - State "NITPICKING" from ""           [2016-05-23 Mon 13:26]
  - State "NITS_SENT"  from "NITPICKING" [2016-05-23 Mon 13:25]
```

It works properly if I use buffer-local keywords instead of defining `org-todo-keywords` in my init file. But this is the global setup that I need, and I'd prefer to do it the way I've done it.

Is there something wrong with my code? Why would only get messed up for a single state?

---

Edit (in response to @nispio):

This behavior occurs even when I start emacs with `emacs -q` and then manually evaluate the `setq` command above.

After some further experimentation, it also seems that the same behavior occurs regardless of the starting state. So, for instance, if I open a `.org` file with a headline in the `ACS_RECEIVED` state and execute `org-todo`, it puts me in the next (`ACS_ASSIGNED`) state, but without syntax highlighting; the next execution of `org-todo` puts me in the initial (`NITPICKING`) state, with proper syntax highlighting, and it works correctly from there.

---

Further edit: the problem is that the headlines were empty apart from the TODO state. I wanted the headline to be empty to make my agenda view cleaner, since the name of the org file together with the TODO state is all the info I need at a glance. But it seems that having an empty headline means that the TODO state is interpreted as the title, which is why the first call to `org-todo` sets me in the initial state.

So, I would like to refine my question to the following: is there any way to have headlines that are empty apart from the TODO state?

Comment: Can you re-produce it with `emacs -q`?  It works as expected for me.

Comment: @nispio Yes, the same thing happens with `emacs -q`; I've edited the post to reflect this, and added further information.